# Find all objects, that's nested properties have desired value

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have collection with the following (sample) documents:

```
{
   "label": "Tree",
   "properties": {
       "height": {
           "type": "int",
           "label": "Height",
           "description": "In meters"
       },
       "coordinates": {
           "type": "coords",
           "label": "Coordinates"
       },
       "age": {
           "type": "int",
           "label": "Age"
       }
   }
}
```

Keys in the *properties* attribute are different for almost each of the documents in collection.

I want to **find all documents that have at least one property of given type**.

What I'm looking for is to query this for `{"properties.*.type": "coords"}`. But this is not working as it is only my invention of mongo query.

Every help I was able to find concerned the `$elemMatch` operator which I can not use here because *properties* is an object, not an array.

Comment: Do you have other properties with the `"coords"` type other than `"properties.coordinates"` property?

Comment: Yes. This is only an example.

Answer (score 1):

Hi as per my knowledge in mongodb not provide this kind of search. So for finding this first I separated out all keys using map-reduce and then find query form so below code will help you

```
    var mapReduce = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "collectionName",
    "map": function() {
    for (var key in this.properties) {
        emit(key, null);
    }
    },
    "reduce": function(key, stuff) {
    return null;
    },
    "out": "collectionName" + "_keys"
})

db[mapReduce.result].distinct("_id").forEach(function(data) {
    findkey = [];

    findkey.push("properties." + data + ".type");
    var query = {};
    query[findkey] = "coords";

    var myCursor = db.collectionName.find(query);

    while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
    print(tojson(myCursor.next()));
    }


})
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't support searches on keys - things like `properties.*` to match all subkeys of `properties`, etc. You shouldn't have arbitrary keys or keys that you don't know about in your schema, unless they are just for display, generally, because you will not be able to interact with them very easily in MongoDB.

If you do want to store dynamic attributes, the best approach is usually an array like the following:

```
{
    "properties" : [
        { 
            "key" : "height", 
            "value" : { 
                "type" : "Int", 
                "label" : "Height", 
                "description" : "In meters" 
             } 
         },
         ...
     ]
}
```

Efficient querying for your use case

> find all documents that have at least one property of given type

results from an index on `{ "key" : 1 }`:

```
db.test.find({ "properties.key" : { "$in" : ["height", "coordinates", "age"] } })
```